# The radical of $k[T_1,T_2]/(T_1 ^2,T_2 ^2,T_1 T_2)$?

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $A=k[T_1,T_2]/(T_1 ^2,T_2 ^2,T_1 T_2)$ with k a field and $X=A/rad(A)$. Then in a paper, it says that there is a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/(T_1) \rightarrow 0$.

I think $rad(A)=<\overline{T_1}, \overline{T_2}>$, so I can't get this short exact sequence. Who can tell me where I'm wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I believe that's the radical. You have map $A \to A$ given by multiplication by $T_1$ with kernel $(T_1,T_2)$, and hence an injection $X \to A$. This composes with the natural surjection $A \to A/(T_1)$ to give the zero map, and dimension counting gives exactness.

Comment: @lokodiz Get it. Thank you.